# How can I paste HYPERLINK formula in Google Sheets cell, to make it clickable link with defined text?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, links, google-sheets-cell-format, copy-paste

I got a script that takes some data and prepares it to paste into Google Sheets cells, some of which are supposed to be links with custom text. But when I paste hyperlink formula the script created, which is consistent with code you get, when manually making hyperlinks, it's pasted as simple text.

What I paste:

```
=HYPERLINK("https://example.com";"link name")|w||=HYPERLINK("https://example.com";"link name")|1,01
```

I separate it into columns with custom character '|' separator.

What I get (ignore formatting):

[image: get]

What I want to have:

[image: want]

What do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... I've been already trying to fix this a couple of times before and I could never find a solution, but when you finally post a question here, you somehow find the answer in 5 minutes on your own. So here's solution:

**Select cells you want to format as link, click FORMAT menu, NUMBER submenu and even though AUTOMATIC is already selected with check sign, when you select it anyway, links show up in cells properly!**

[image]